# Kentico GetAzureFile.aspx badhashtext error

Tags: kentico, media-library

I've recently copied a Kentico 10 environment to a new development environment, and upgraded it to Kentico 12. I believe the problem occurred after the upgrade, not after the copy (of the site and database). The new environment is also using a different URL than the original, and I have a valid license key for the new URL.
The site functions correctly, except for images. Unfortunately, all media library images that are loaded using GetAzureFile.aspx are failing to load. Attempting to access one causes a redirect to
/CMSMessages/accessdenied.aspx?resstring=dialogs.badhashtext&hash=...

I assumed the problem might be a different `CMSHashStringSalt` in the new environment's web.config, but it is the same as that of the original environment.

Per [this documentation](https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/securing-websites/developing-secure-websites/query-string-hashing), I have attempted to re-save some of the images to see if they would begin loading but that did not help.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might tackle this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that `GetAzureFile()` is something you should be using "publically", I believe that's meant to be an internal handler.  You should be using the permanent URLs for media libraries hooked up to external storage.

Also, your provider code could need to be updated.  Check out the [documentation](https://docs.xperience.io/custom-development/working-with-physical-files-using-the-api/configuring-file-system-providers/configuring-azure-storage#ConfiguringAzurestorage-MappingfilestoAzurestorage).